# Why is the variable not updating properly in java?

Tags: java, jtextarea

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.applet.Applet;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;

//This class is where we set up all the questions.
class party{

  int panel_number = 0;
  int party_score = 0;
  JFrame frame = new JFrame();
  String target_word;
  String user_text;
  String label_text;
  JLabel question_frame;
  JPanel pane;
  JPanel panel;

  // public void title_page(){
  //   JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to The Party Project!");
  // }

  public void picture_questions(int question_number){
    String photo1;
    String photo2;
    String photo3;
    String photo4;
    String question_header;

      if (question_number == 1){
        question_header = "           Which party appeals to you the most?";
        photo1 = "Rooftop.jpg";
        photo2 = "CollegeParty.jpg";
        photo3 = "Business.jpg";
        photo4 = "PoolParty.jpg";
          image_question(photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4, question_header);
      }

      else if (question_number == 2){
        question_header = "             What is your favorite game?";
        photo1 = "twister.jpg";
        photo2 = "ellen.jpg";
        photo3 = "bp.jpg";
        photo4 = "cornhole.jpg";
        image_question(photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4, question_header);
      }

      else if (question_number == 3){
        question_header = "             Which musician do you want to party to?";
        photo1 = "GratefulDead.jpg";
        photo2 = "justin.jpg";
        photo3 = "Taylor.jpg";
        photo4 = "Beatles.jpg";
        image_question(photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4, question_header);
      }

      else if (question_number == 4){
        question_header = "             Which describes you at a party?";
        photo1 = "passedout.jpg";
        photo2 = "kissing.jpg";
        photo3 = "dancing.jpg";
        photo4 = "selfie.jpg";
        image_question(photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4, question_header);
      }

      else if (question_number == 5){
        question_header = "           Which is your favorite musician?";
        photo1 = "Queen.jpg";
        photo2 = "OneD.jpg";
        photo3 = "Kanye.jpg";
        photo4 = "Chainsmokers.jpg";
        image_question(photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4, question_header);
      }

      else if (question_number == 6){
        question_header = "            Which outfit would you wear to a party?";
        photo1 = "toga.jpg";
        photo2 = "Santa.jpg";
        photo3 = "Business.jpg";
        photo4 = "Onezie.jpg";
        image_question(photo1, photo2, photo3, photo4, question_header);
      }
}


  public void text_questions(int question_number){
    String answer1;
    String answer2;
    String answer3;
    String answer4;
    String question_header;

    if (question_number == 1){
      answer1 = "Drenched";
      answer2 = "<html><body> I like to get a good workout  in when I party but not too sweaty</html>";
      answer3 = "Not huge into the sweating scene";
      answer4 = "Don't make me take off my jacket";
      question_header = "How sweaty do you like to get when you party?";
      multiple_choice_question(answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, question_header);
    }

    if (question_number == 2){
      answer1 = "<html><body> My computer so I could  code for the rest of my life</html>";
      answer2 = "My crush";
      answer3 = "A good book";
      answer4 = "My favorite drink";
      question_header = "If you were stranded on a desert island, what would you bring?";
      multiple_choice_question(answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, question_header);
    }

    if (question_number == 3){
      answer1 = "Never eat pizza again";
      answer2 = "Have to refer to professors as 'Sire'";
      answer3 = "Kiss a live frog";
      answer4 = "Have to comment every line of your code";
      question_header = "Would you rather...";
      multiple_choice_question(answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, question_header);
    }

    if (question_number == 4){
      answer1 = "Water";
      answer2 = "Beer";
      answer3 = "Wine";
      answer4 = "Moonshine";
      question_header = "What is your favorite drink (21+ only)";
      multiple_choice_question(answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, question_header);
    }

    if (question_number == 5){
      answer1 = "<html><body>The environment, how could you care about anything else when our globe is heating up at an irreprable speed. No more skiing? WHAT ABOUT THE POLAR BEARS!?!?</html>";
      answer2 = "<html><body>Artificial intelligence, Have you seen 2001 a Space Oddesy? Her? Self-Driving Ubers? Computers are taking over and not even Matthew can save us!</html>";
      answer3 = "<html><body>Ending gun violence, No other country has even close to as much gun violence as we do. Every statistic shows that owning a gun makes your chances of dying from gun violence much higher!</html>";
      answer4 = "Dinosaurs";
      question_header = "What are you most passionate about?";
      multiple_choice_question(answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, question_header);
    }
  }

  public void user_question(){
    String[] target = {"music", "food", "boys", "girls", "live music", "dancing", "drinks", "good", "fun", "people", "not crowded", "band", "college"};
    String question = "In a few words, describe your ideal party.";
    System.out.println("howdy");
    input_question(target, question);
  }

  public void image_question(String question_photo1, String question_photo2, String question_photo3, String question_photo4, String label_text){
    //This panel will display four images that the user will choose from.
    panel = new JPanel();
//    question_frame.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    JButton button1;
    JButton button2;
    JButton button3;
    JButton button4;
    frame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    question_frame = new JLabel(label_text);
    panel.add(question_frame, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    button1 = new JButton();
    JPanel inner = new JPanel();
    inner.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 2));
    button1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(question_photo1)); //Width: 312 Height: 295
    button1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    button1.setActionCommand("1");
    inner.add(button1);
    button2 = new JButton();
    button2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(question_photo2));
    button2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    button2.setActionCommand("2");
    inner.add(button2);
    button3 = new JButton();
    button3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(question_photo3));
    button3.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    button3.setActionCommand("3");
    inner.add(button3);
    button4 = new JButton();
    button4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(question_photo4));
    button4.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
    button4.setActionCommand("4");
    inner.add(button4);
    panel.add(inner, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    // ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Alex.jpg");
    // fram`e.getContentPane().add(new JLabel(icon), BorderLayout.EAST);
    panel.setVisible(true);
    frame.add(panel);
    frame.toFront();
    ActionListener al = new click();
    button1.addActionListener(al);
    button2.addActionListener(al);
    button3.addActionListener(al);
    button4.addActionListener(al);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public void multiple_choice_question(String AnswerA, String AnswerB, String AnswerC, String AnswerD, String label_text){
    //This panel displays a 4 answer multiple choice question that they user will choose from.
    frame = new JFrame();
    pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    question_frame = new JLabel(label_text);
    pane.add(question_frame, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    JPanel center = new JPanel();
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(0,2);
    center.setLayout(grid);
    pane.add(center, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    ActionListener al = new click();
    addAButton(AnswerA, center, al, "1",1);
    addAButton(AnswerB, center, al, "2",1);
    addAButton(AnswerC, center, al, "3",1);
    addAButton(AnswerD, center, al, "4",1);
    frame.add(pane);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  }

  public void input_question(String[] target, String question){
    //This panel will display a question and chance for the user to input their answer.
    frame = new JFrame();
    pane = new JPanel();
    JTextArea user_input = new JTextArea(25, 25);
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pane.add(user_input, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    question_frame = new JLabel(question);
    pane.add(question_frame, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    ActionListener al = new click();
    JButton button = new JButton("I'm Done");
    button.addActionListener(al);
    button.setActionCommand("5");
    pane.add(button, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    frame.add(pane);
    frame.setSize(600, 600);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    for (int i = 0; i <target.length; i++){
      //user_input.toLowerCase();
      System.out.println(user_input.getText());
      if (user_input.getText().indexOf(target[i]) >=0){
        System.out.println("ho ho ho");
    }
  }
}

    public void party() {
    panel_number++;
    System.out.println(panel_number);
       if (panel_number == 1){
         picture_questions(1);
       }
       else if(panel_number == 2){
         picture_questions(2);
       }
       else if(panel_number == 3){
         picture_questions(3);
       }
       else if (panel_number == 4){
         picture_questions(4);
       }
       else if(panel_number == 5){
         picture_questions(5);
       }
       else if(panel_number == 6){
         text_questions(1);
       }
       else if(panel_number == 7){
         text_questions(2);
       }
       else if(panel_number == 8){
         text_questions(3);
       }
       else if(panel_number == 9){
         text_questions(4);
       }
       else if(panel_number == 10){
         text_questions(5);
       }
       else if(panel_number == 11){
         text_questions(6);
       }
      else if (panel_number == 12){
         user_question();
      }
  }

  private static void addAButton(String text, Container container, ActionListener al, String actionCommand, int allignment_number) {
       JButton button = new JButton(text);
       button.setAlignmentX(Component.CENTER_ALIGNMENT);
       container.add(button);
       button.addActionListener(al);
       button.setActionCommand(actionCommand);
  }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        party myGUI = new party();
    myGUI.party();
    }



class ClassParty{
 //This class will read txt documents created by users and suggest a party that everyone would enjoy!
}

class click implements ActionListener{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
     party partier = new party();
      if (event.getActionCommand().equals("1")){
        party_score++;
      }
      else if  (event.getActionCommand().equals("2")){
        party_score++;
      }
      else if  (event.getActionCommand().equals("3")){
        party_score++;
      }
      else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("4")){
        party_score++;
      }
      else if (event.getActionCommand().equals("5")){
        frame.dispose();
      }
      frame.dispose();
      panel.setVisible(false);
      party();
      //System.out.println(party_score);
     /* creates a GUI that presents the user with a question with clickable answers that gives you the next question
    when you finish answering. It plays jeapordy theme music and has a picture Alex Trabeck. It has a status bar
    that tells you how close you are to finishing the program. */
  }
}
}
```

The 12th panel is not showing up, it is only updating the variable until 11. It should show the `user_question` after the 11th panel, text_question. Also the `user_question` is not properly using indexOf to detect the target word from the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have 6 picture questions and 5 text questions.

Why is there no `picture_questions(6);`, but a `text_questions(6);`?

---

Why does your `ActionListener` create a new party instance? It's not needed and confusing.

```
class click implements ActionListener{
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
     party partier = new party();
     ....
   }
}
```

---

Regarding your use of the `indexOf()` method to test the user input: the code would work, but you are testing the user input at frame construction time, which is long before the user had any chance of entering his text.

The loop to test what the user has entered belongs into an action listener.